# How to make a textbox same width for all browsers

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I have a textbox in a fixed width. I'm struggling with browser compatibility. When I fix the width in Firefox,Chrome  do not show proper,it show more lenght towards right.

UPDATED My code

HTML

```
<form name="welcomeDiv1" id="welcomeDiv1">
<tr class="unsortable" >

<tr>
 <td>
<input type="text" class="textbox_form" name="content" id="content" />
</td>

<td>
<input type="text" class="textbox_form2" name="content2" id="content2"/ >
</td>

 <td>
 <input type="text" class="textbox_form3" name="content3" id="content3"/ >
 </td>

 <td>   
  <input type="text" class="textbox_form4" name="content4" id="content4" />
  </td>

<td>
<input type="text" class="textbox_form5" name="content5" id="content5"/ >
</td>

<td>
 <input type="text" class="textbox_form6" name="content6" id="content6" />
 </td>  

<td> <input type="submit" class="textbox_form7"  value="+"  name="submit" class="globalinsert_button"/></td>

  </tr>
 </form>
```

CSS

```
.textbox_form {
               margin:0 0 0 1px;
               width:162px;
               height:30px;
               background-color:#C2FFC2;
    }
    .textbox_form2 {
              margin:0 0 0 -3px;
              width:329px;
              height:30px;
              background-color:#C2FFC2;
    }
    .textbox_form3 {
              margin:0 0 0 -3px;
              width:386px;
              height:30px;
              background-color:#C2FFC2;
    }
    .textbox_form4 {
              margin:0 0 0 -3px;
              width:138px;
              height:30px;
              background-color:#C2FFC2;
    }
    .textbox_form5 {
              margin:0 0 0 -2px;
              width:158px;
              height:30px;
              background-color:#C2FFC2;
    }
    .textbox_form6 {
              margin:0 0 0 -2px;
              width:204px;
              height:30px;
              background-color:#C2FFC2;
    }
    .textbox_form7 {
             margin:0 0 0 17px;
    }
```

I need textbox to be placed exactly in same in all browsers. but it still remains the same issue

Answer (score 2):

Your style attribute not closed,check.

Try separate css style like this:  add class 'textbox_form' in each textbox

```
<style>
    .textbox_form {
        margin-left: 5px;
        margin-top: 5px;
        width: 150px;
        background-color:#C2FFC2;
    }
    </style>

    <td>
    <input type="text" class="textbox_form" name="content" id="content" border:0px">
    </td>
```

Comment: its remains same issue

Answer (score 0):

You're doing the markup wrong for inline styling. It should read like this:

```
<input type="text" style="margin:0 0 0 -3px; width:386px; height:30px; background:#C2FFC2; border:none" name="content3" id="content3" />
```

Also, use an external CSS stylesheet! Otherwise you're repeating a lot of code.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Firstly, your code is invalid HTML. The `name` and `id` attributes appear to have been put inside the `style` attributes; this is wrong and is making the code invald. This needs to be fixed.</strike>

Secondly, I strongly recommend using a separate CSS file for your styles. This will help you avoid repetition, and also make it easier to give similar fields the same styles.

[EDIT] The above two points have now been fixed in the question.

Finally, my guess as to the ultimate cause of your cross-browser problem is that your page is probably rendering in Quirks Mode. If your page doesn't have a valid `<!DOCTYPE>` at the start, it will go into quirks mode, which will cause different browsers to render the page differently. Fix this (and the other HTML errors you've got), and you'll get better cross-browser consistency.

Answer (score 0):

Set `box-sizing: border-box` (along with its `-moz-`prefixed counterpart) to `input[type="text"]`. This makes default browser-themed paddings etc. not affect the resulting dimensions, and also makes `input` elements obey the same box model as `select` and `textarea` elements (they have implicit `box-sizing: border-box` by default in most browsers), making form styling easier.